# Add event listener to Polymer Webcomponent by id

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

I'm just starting to try using Webcomponents, and I'm running into an issue trying to add event listeners to elements in my custom webcomponent.

My template looks like this:

```
<dom-module id="quadimageview">
    <template>
        <template is="dom-if" if="[[!issingleview]]">
            <div id="gridViewContainer" class="grid-view">
                <div id="topLeftCell" class="grid-cell">
                    <select id="colorTL" class="color-select" value="{{TLColor::change}}">
                        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[colors]]">
                            <option selected$="[[optionSelected(item.value, TLColor)]]" value="[[item.value]]">[[item.name]]</option>
                        </template>
                    </select>
                    <imageviewer id="gridTLImgViewer"
                                      definedscan="[[TLColor]]"
                                      viewerheight="100%"
                                      viewerposition="none"
                                      zoomcontrol>
                    </imageviewer>
                </div>
                <div id="topRightCell" class="grid-cell">
                    <select id="colorTR" class="color-select" value="{{TRColor::change}}">
                        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[colors]]">
                            <option selected$="[[optionSelected(item.value, TRColor)]]" value="[[item.value]]">[[item.name]]</option>
                        </template>
                    </select>
                    <imageviewer id="gridTRImgViewer"
                                      definedscan="[[TRColor]]"
                                      viewerheight="100%"
                                      viewerposition="none">
                    </imageviewer>
                </div>

                <div id="bottomLeftCell" class="grid-cell">
                    <select id="colorBL" class="color-select" value="{{BLColor::change}}">
                        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[colors]]">
                            <option selected$="[[optionSelected(item.value, BLColor)]]" value="[[item.value]]">[[item.name]]</option>
                        </template>
                    </select>
                    <imageviewer id="gridBLImgViewer"
                                      definedscan="[[BLColor]]"
                                      viewerheight="100%"
                                      viewerposition="none">
                    </imageviewer>
                </div>
                <div id="bottomRightCell" class="grid-cell">
                    <select id="colorBR" class="color-select" value="{{BRColor::change}}">
                        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[colors]]">
                            <option selected$="[[optionSelected(item.value, BRColor)]]" value="[[item.value]]">[[item.name]]</option>
                        </template>
                    </select>
                    <imageviewer id="gridBRImgViewer"
                                      definedscan="[[BRColor]]"
                                      viewerheight="100%"
                                      viewerposition="none">
                    </imageviewer>
                </div>
            </div>
        </template>
    </template>
</dom-module>
```

And my script looks like this:

```
    <script>
        require("jquery-ui/ui/widgets/resizable");
        require("leaflet.sync");

        class Quadimageview extends Polymer.LightDomElement {

            constructor() {
                super();
                this.loadedViewers;

                this.TLColor = 'EngineeringBlue';
                this.TRColor = 'EngineeringGreen';
                this.BLColor = 'EngineeringYellow';
                this.BRColor = 'EngineeringRed';

                this.colors = [
                    { value: 'EngineeringBlue', name: 'FL-Blue' },
                    { value: 'EngineeringGreen', name: 'FL-Green' },
                    { value: 'EngineeringRed', name: 'FL-Red' },
                    { value: 'EngineeringYellow', name: 'FL-Yellow' },
                    { value: 'EngineeringBfBlue', name: 'BF-Blue' },
                    { value: 'EngineeringBfGreen', name: 'BF-Green' },
                    { value: 'EngineeringBfRed', name: 'BF-Red' },
                ];
            }

            static get is() { return 'quadimageview'; }

            static get properties() {
                return {
                    issingleview: {
                        type: Boolean,
                        value: false
                    }
                }
            } 

            ready() {
                super.ready();
                this.initialize();
            }

            optionSelected(value, match) {
                return value == match;
            }

            setupSync(viewer) {                
                console.log(this.loadedViewers);

                if (this.loadedViewers) {
                    this.loadedViewers.forEach(function (element) {
                        if (element.map && viewer.map) {
                            element.map.sync(viewer.map);
                            viewer.map.sync(element.map);
                        }
                    });

                    this.loadedViewers.push(viewer);
                }
                else {
                    this.loadedViewers = [ viewer ];
                }
            }

            initialize() {
                console.log('> Init TL...');
                this.$.gridTLImgViewer.addEventListener('ImageViewerLoaded', function () { this.setupSync(this.$.gridTLImgViewer); }.bind(this));

                console.log('>> Init TR...');
                this.$.gridTRImgViewer.addEventListener('ImageViewerLoaded', function () { this.setupSync(this.$.gridTRImgViewer); }.bind(this));

                console.log('>>> Init BL...');
                this.$.gridBLImgViewer.addEventListener('ImageViewerLoaded', function () { this.setupSync(this.$.gridBLImgViewer); }.bind(this));

                console.log('>>>> Init BR...');
                this.$.gridBRImgViewer.addEventListener('ImageViewerLoaded', function () { this.setupSync(this.$.gridBRImgViewer); }.bind(this));
            }
        }

        window.customElements.define(Quadimageview.is, Quadimageview);
    </script>
```

And my component breaks on 'addEventListener', with the error saying 'Cannot add property "addEventListener" of undefined.  So it seems like the 'this.$.' isn't the right call.  Any hints as to what I'm setting up incorrectly?  Thanks!

Comment: Also: You need to change the custom element's name minimum two words and dash separated. ie  `quad-image-view`  for more detail: https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/custom-elements

Answer (score 1):

As I commented above you need to change custom components name dash separated after there are two way to add an event listener. One is inside the compenent as shown below. Or `this.addEventListener('image-viewer-loaded',this._ImageViewerLoaded)` defined at attached or ready function. So below if an element rendered then its events defined as below.

```
<image-viewer id='gridBLImgViewer'
               definedscan='[[BLColor]]'
               viewerheight="100%"
               viewerposition='none'
               on-image-viewer-loaded='_ImageViewerLoaded'>
</image-viewer>


.....

_ImageViewerLoaded() {
   //Your code here
}
```

in your `image-viewer` components, you will need to assign a function that image loaded. Than add a custom event in order to fire an event at its parent.

```
_ImageViewerLoaded(){
      this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('image-viewer-loaded', {detail: { option}}));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost everything in your element is wrapped in an if statement:

```
<template is="dom-if" if="[[!issingleview]]">
```

And, as you can read [here], "Nodes created dynamically using data binding (including those in dom-repeat and **dom-if** templates) are **not** added to the **this.$ hash**."

That object is just a "shortcut", but you can still query the local dom to find the element. Just use something like

```
this.shadowRoot.getElementById('elementId')
```

or

```
this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#elementId')
```

**Update**: also, at the moment you run `initialize` the elements might not be yet stamped into the page. Just to check, you can run the call in a timeout, just to delay it a few milliseconds:

```
  ready() {
    super.ready();
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.initialize();
    });
  }
```

Also I don't know what you are trying to do there, but I see you are using some jQuery widget. Be sure to check if it works with your setup, because all the libraries that query the DOM by using **document.** *something* are not really compatible with the shadowDom. But that is outside the scope of this question...